# Unable to import request module

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to import the requests module in python but am running into an error. I installed the module using PIP and shows if I run a PIP list but when I try to run the program I am returned this error:

```
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>        
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import logging
  File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Dev\ATBS\.vscode\logging.py", line 2, in <module>
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'logging' has no attribute 'basicConfig' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I removed everything else but "import requests" so there is definitely an issue with the module import itself.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I had another file named logging.py in the project folder. renamed this and now works as should

Comment: If it is solved you should close the topic